# How to copy and work with a github repository on different pcs

Tags: github

So i have a github repository on a windows pc and use the desktop app to work with it. It works fine. Now i want to work on the same repo with a linux pc at my working place but i don't know how to do that.

i downloaded the repo from my github-account and got a zip. i extracted the zip on my desktop: /home/lukas/Schreibtisch/code for hamburg and the name is: codeforhamburgneu-master.

then
1. i startet the terminal with right click and used git init (it said: created empty ...)

2. i used 
   git remote add origin https://github.com//
3. i used git add --all
4. i used git push -u origin master

i get: error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my unsername/my-rep.git'

where did i went wrong?

Now the first push worked and i changed a few things localy and wanted to push again. I get this:

To blabla.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'blabla'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: the first push did not seem to work. it didn't give an error message but my online repo didn't change either. so how can i pull the things i've pushed?

Comment: Do you have a new problem?

Comment: yes, like i said. should i open a new thread? Pushing and pulling does not really seem to work.

Comment: finally i know what went wrong. i forgot to commit before the push. Without a commit its like a gateway to error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going about this incorrectly.  Assuming you already have Git installed somewhere on the Linux box, all you need to do is clone the Git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

Moving around data like this is not really part of the normal Git workflow.  Rather, everyone sharing your repository should be synching up with GitHub.

Here is a link for how to clone a GitHub repository on Linux:

https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Comment: i don't understand the second part of your message: Moving around data like this is not really part of the normal Git workflow. Rather, everyone sharing your repository should be synching up with GitHub but your advice did help. Thx.

Comment: @Lukas I mean that if you want to get a snapshot of a repository, the master source of data is GitHub, not copying the entire workspace onto a thumb drive and moving it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone your repository rather then 'downloading' it:

```
git clone 'https://github.com/my unsername/my-rep.git'
```

Look at github helppages for further instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/